# how to egrep a line which contains one mandatory word and must to have one of optional words

Tags: regex, awk, grep

I need to grep the entire lines which are matching one mandatory word, say "Jan 10" and must contain one of the optional words, say "Crit", "Warn".

Equivalent C expression will be: if (strstr(buf, "Jan 10") && (strstr(buf, "Crit") || strstr(buf, "Warn")))

Note: Tried few answers which are almost close enough to this, but still wasn't helping me. My log file will contain different levels Crit, Warn, Info, Debg. But I want only Crit or Warn but Date should be Jan 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess grep is not the best choice here, for regex not supporting logical operation directly. And I prefer to use `awk` for these stuff, which is both a programming language and cmd tool for regex.

```
awk '/Jan 10/ && (/Crit/ || /Warn/)' your_text_file
```

Comment: awk is awesome in doing logical operations I think. More than grep this seems to be simplistic.

Comment: Nice! Can also be done using grep like so: [link](https://regex101.com/r/lN6hK4/2)

Answer (score 2):

With GNU grep:

```
grep 'Jan 10' file | grep -e 'Crit' -e 'Warn'
```

Answer (score 1):

grep "Jan 10" log_file | egrep "Crit|Warn"

Hope this helps.